# Unit testing with an Active Record based framework

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a framework which based its ORM on the [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Every table I have in my database is bound to a model in my code.

I want to unit test these models, so I started by extracting every `save()` and `update()` call from models, so that changes are made only on objects, and they only get persisted once needed.

I don't know how I can apply this strategy in this case though. I have a `Chat` model, which a `User` is part of, and the `User` can add a `ChatNote` to the `Chat`.

Here's the current implementation :

```
// User.php
public function addChatNote($chatNoteContent, Chat $chat)
{
    $chatNote = new ChatNote();
    $chatNote->content = $chatNoteContent;
    $chatNote->save();

    $chat->note()->associate($chatNote);
    $chat->save();
}
```

Now to my eyes there are tons of problems here, but the `save()` calls are really ruining my chance to do proper unit testing here.

I thought about creating the `ChatNote` before using that method, but what class should be responsible for creating it ? I could also save it elsewhere, and save the `Chat` elsewhere but then is the `User` really responsible for anything else than associating the `ChatNote` to the `Chat` ? And where should the `save()` be made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user3807702 said you can employ the [`AbstractFactory`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern or the [`Factory method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to handle your Unit Testing of the application. E.g.

```
public function addChatNote($chatNoteContent, Chat $chat)
{
    $chatNote = $this->chatNoteFactory->newInstance();
    $chatNote->content = $chatNoteContent;
    $chatNote->save();

    $chat->note()->associate($chatNote);
    $chat->save();
}
```

This will help you to create a `ChatNote` [mock](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) that will not engage any database communication during testing.

```
$chatNote = $this->getMockBuilder(ChatNote::class)
                ->disableConstructor()
                ->setMethods(['save'])
                ->getMock();

$chatNoteFactoryMock = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(chatNoteFactoryMock::class)
    ->getMock();

$chatNoteFactoryMock
   ->method('newInstance')
   ->willReturn($chatNote);

//Pass the chat note factory mock to the User
```

The same you will do with the `Chat` object - pass its mock instead to `addChatNote`. So you will get pure Unit Tests w/o DB communication.

Still should say that `save` objects inside `User` could be considered as violation of the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The `User` should be bothered to store `Chat` and `ChatNote` into DB. Would be good to put the `saves` outside: you can do it explicit way or by using proxy objects, AOP frameworks, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Indeed some classicist xunit testers also argue that any collaboration with external resources, such as a database or filesystem, should use doubles. Partly this is due to non-determinism risk, partly due to speed. While I think this is a useful guideline, I don't treat using doubles for external resources as an absolute rule. If talking to the resource is stable and fast enough for you then there's no reason not to do it in your unit tests.

([Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html))

You seem to be using Laravel. The framework provides out of the box some easy ways to integrate [the database in your tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing).

Antoher common practice is using a separate, in-memory database for testing. You can even create the schema from scratch (running all migrations) before each test. Just add this to your `phpunit.xml`:

```
<php>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a ChatNoteFactory that would return a ChatNote, passing a content through.